# How do I connect to the postgres from my home OS using a GUI client like postico?

Tags: postgresql, cookiecutter-django

I am running the Django Cookiecutter on Docker and tried to connect to the postgres database using Postico, a GUI client on my laptop.

The credentials I used was basically the same as `.envs/.local/.postgres` Yet I still cannot connect.

I wonder what's the issue that's blocking me from doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that I wasn't aware that Docker allows you to state which ports get mapped to the host OS.

See https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network_mode for details.

Specifically, I needed to go to `local.yml` under `postgres` definition and add:

```
ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

Then restart the docker.

In case you want to map different port number note that the syntax is

```
the HOST:CONTAINER format
```